# Purpose of '~/.cache' directory and when is it safe to delete?

Tags: home-directory, delete, cache

What is the purpose of every user's `~/.cache` directory?

Under which circumstances can it be deleted, when should one be careful about its contents?

Comment: See the link I gave you

Answer (score 6):

This is by no means a definite answer.

According to the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` which defaults to `$HOME/.cache` holds

> [...]user-specific non-essential (cached) data[...]

It is however not specified what constitutes 'non-essential data'. Furthermore an application might not play by freedesktop rules and put whatever it wants in `.cache`.

Browsing through my cache folder, I find things like

- Browser caches. Safe enough to delete.
- Thumbnails. Will be recreated if deleted.
- `software-center`. Wasn't sure about that. Contains a file `apthistory.p` with your - well - history of apt. Moved it out of the way and it was recreated on the next start of the Ubuntu Software Center.
- I guess the Software Updater stores package lists `apt-file`. Will be downloaded anew if deleted.
- icon-cache. Like thumbs, will also be recreated.
- `compizconfig-1`. Contains binary files; compiz seems to cache its configuration in optimized form from `~/.config/compizconfig-1`.
- `dconf`. This directory actually doesn't belong to `$USER` but root. Mine contains a single non plaintext file `user`. Since you can't delete it anyway without sudoing... No problem.
- And some more directories which I don't deem critical.

In summary, I believe it perfectly safe to empty the cache folder. In fact I do this from time to time and never experienced faulty behaviour afterwards.

**This is not a guarantee though, just my two cents and a (somewhat) educated guess.**